# Angular Universal, infinite loading error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

**Summary:** Long question so here's the quick summary. *I can run the commands `ng build && ng run app-name:server` and `npm run dev:server` successfully and see no errors on console whenever I try to connect to server. But page is loading infinitely. I have tried to apply NgxSsrTimeoutModule.forRoot({ timeout: 500 }) nothing changed. Made other changes but saw no progress. Really stuck at this point having headaches.*

Hello,
I'm trying to convert a SPA Angular application to an SSR-compatible one. Application is a little bit chunky, so I couldn't create a new SSR rendered application and move the modules to that one, one by one. First, my versions are:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.2
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.1.2
@angular/cli                    13.1.2
@angular/platform-server        13.1.3
@nguniversal/builders           13.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.0.2
@schematics/angular             13.1.2
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.5.4
```

I have made some changes to get development server working. First change was on angular.json. I had error **Angular Universal Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace**:

```
"serve-ssr": {
  "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "appName:build:production",
      "serverTarget": "appName:server:production"
    }, 
   "development": ...
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

- First change was on angular.json. [Referring to this issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2158#issuecomment-857434860)

I have changed as this:

```
"serve-ssr": {
  "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
  "options": { "browserTarget": "appName:build", "serverTarget": "appName:server"},
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "appName:build:production",
      "serverTarget": "appName:server:production"
    }
  }
},
```

- Second change was on ServerModule.

We had an application starter basically an Angular service requesting an appConfig.json to make application configurations. I had **Could not load file '../../assets/config/appConfig.json'** which is an error thrown from that service. So basic ServerModule changed as this;

```
import { NgModule, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { INITIAL_CONFIG, PlatformConfig, ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgxSsrTimeoutModule } from '@ngx-ssr/timeout';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    NgxSsrTimeoutModule.forRoot({ timeout: 500 })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {
  constructor(@Inject(INITIAL_CONFIG) private config: PlatformConfig) {
    this.config.useAbsoluteUrl = true;
  }
}
```

- Also solved the "window not defined" error by adding `domino` library
  to the server code.

After changing this, I could successfully run the comman `npm run dev:ssr`. Take note that, before doing this, I could run the command `ng build && ng run app-name:server` but not `npm run dev:ssr`. And after that, I had a running **Node server** on my localhost:4200 but page is always in loading state, I could see nothing on network tab (Chrome Dev Tools), no client side application taking action and nothing on console (just says Messages received, value changed...). After all these, I implemented *appShellRender and *appShellNoRender directives, and just decided to render a loading animation in the server, nothing changed;

app.component.ts:

```
<div *appShellRender>
  <app-loading-animation></app-loading-animation>
</div>

<div *appShellNoRender>
  <ng-container appCardQuery appSystemIdTracker>
    <mat-sidenav-container>

        <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
          <app-side-nav (closeSideNav)="sidenav.close()"></app-side-nav>
        </mat-sidenav>

        <mat-sidenav-content (scroll) = "onScroll($event)">

          <ng-container *ngIf="isToolbarOn">
            <app-toolbar (SideNavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-toolbar>
          </ng-container>
          <main>
            <!-- <div style="background-color: black; width: 250px;height: 250px;" (click)="testClick()"></div> -->
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </main>
          <div class="spacer30"></div> 
          <ng-container *ngIf="isAppAboutOn">
            <app-about></app-about>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**server.ts:**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
const domino = require('domino');

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/appName/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  const win = domino.createWindow(indexHtml);
  global['window'] = win;
  global['document'] = win.document;
  global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
  global['screen'] = win.screen;

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**Error Possibilities**
I see no errors on console but there's obviously something wrong.
We're using AgmCoreModule which is an Angular component to use Maps on application. Also leaflet.

index.js:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

These might be causing errors?